# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting to program with JS and PHP and my question is why the console give this error, I search a lot of websites but without clues about this. If you can help I'll apreciate it

```js
<script>  
  $(function(){
    $("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "registro.php",
        data: $("#form_members").serialize(),
        success: function()
      });
    });
    return false;          
  });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: PROTIP: Tag your question with the *programming language* you are using.

Comment: PROTIP: read the error

Comment: PROTIP: post the error along with your question

Answer (score 3):

you forgot `{}` after `function()`

Updated JS

```
$(function () {
$("#btn_enviar").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "registro.php",
        data: $("#form_members").serialize(),
        success: function (){}
    });
});
return false;
});
```